# What is difference of should.throw(), should.Throw(), and expect to.throw()?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai

I read the [the document](http://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should) that chai.should() and chai.expect() should work in the same way, but when I try to catch the error, it seems different. As my understanding that I can use should() to assert promise chain as

```
myfunction.should.be.rejectedWith(Error)
```

However, as the function will throw the error before the promise chain, the error would not go inside the promise chain, I can't use this method. Then I use the methods as below.

As you can see,

```
() => myFunctionA(name).should.throw('argument name is undefine');
```

and

```
expect(() => myFunctionA(name).to.throw('Argument "stackName" is undefined');
```

according to the document, they should have the same effect, or work in the same way, however, the former will always pass, even I removed the error throwing from my source code. It will just passed anyway. Only the later one work properly. Is anyone know why? Do you have better idea to test "Throw Error" like this?

```js
function myFunctionA(name) {
    if (!name) {
        throw new Error('argument name is undefine')
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
}


it.only('should throw Error if name is null|undefined ', () => {
    let name;
    () => myFunctionA(name).should.throw('argument name is undefine'); //this would pass no matter how
    () => myFunctionA(name).should.Throw('argument name is undefine'); //this would pass no matter how
    expect(() => myFunctionA(name).to.throw('Argument "stackName" is undefined'); // this will do the assert properly, this is work
    return myFunctionA(name).should.throw(Error);// this will failed to catch the Error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the first two cases:

```
    () => myFunctionA(name).should.throw('argument name is undefine'); //this would pass no matter how
    () => myFunctionA(name).should.Throw('argument name is undefine'); //this would pass no matter how
```

You are creating an anonymous function `() => myFunctionA(name)` that is never called, so you are not actually calling myFunctionA

For the last case

```
myFunctionA(name).should.throw(Error);// this will failed to catch the Error
```

This is not working because your code throws an error before the `.should` can run. From the documentation [here][1] you should use it like you are doing in the 3 case.